# FEniCS: how to access coordinates when writing an equation for a trial function

Tags: finite-element, python, fenics

I need to solve the following equation in FEniCS:
$$
\boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  f(y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - g(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
  - g(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+f(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
 \end{pmatrix}=0.
$$
As far as I understand, the weak form will look like:
$$
\int_{\Omega} \begin{pmatrix}
  f(y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - g(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\
  - g(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+f(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \nabla v \, \mathrm{d}x =
       0 \quad \forall v \in V.
$$
I have problems expressing this equation in FEniCS. I figured I need something like this:

```py
u = TrialFunction(V)
v = TestFunction(V)
g = as_vector((u.dx(0), u.dx(1))) # <-- modify here?
a = dot(g, grad(v))*dx
u = Function(V)
solve(a == Constant(0) * v * dx, u, bc)
```

How to add something that depends on coordinates $x$, $y$ to the variable `g` above?

Also do I have to write `Constant(0) * v * dx` as the right part? Can it be just 0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x = V.cell().x
```

then use `x[0]` and `x[1]` as $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Right-hand side of `LinearVariationalProblem` needs to be rank 1 form - this is expressed by dependendnce on `TestFunction` and independence on `TrialFunction`.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in the new FEniCS.

Comment: @facetus since this is related to the working of a library, it is best to ask this question on the fenics forum or google group.

Comment: I know. But other people who can try to look here for an answer don't.